# How can i condition ng-readonly inside textarea

Tags: angularjs

I'm looking for a way to condition a `ng-readonly` inside an `ng-if` statement.. i tried it in a few way, this is my latest vesion..

```
ng-if="note.owner_image === user.image "  ng-readonly="false"
```

need some assistant..

```
<textarea 
                  class="wm-textarea-notes"
                  ng-model="noteEdit.note_value" 
                  columns="1"  
                  placeholder="Add a note"
                  ng-readonly="true"
              ng-if="note.owner_image === user.image "  ng-readonly="false"
              ng-if="note.owner_image === "" "  ng-readonly="false


                  ></textarea>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

ng-if is used to hide or show the element based on the condition given.
if you want the condition to apply to ng-readonly, you should put it in the ng-readonly attribute:

```
<textarea 
    class="wm-textarea-notes"
    ng-model="noteEdit.note_value" 
    columns="1"  
    placeholder="Add a note"
    ng-readonly="note.owner_image !== user.image || note.owner_image !== ''">
</textarea>
```

Answer (score 2):

That's not what `ng-if` does. It just creates or removes the element based upon the value.

What you want is to have a scope method that makes those tests, let's call it `isReadOnly` and have your `textarea` like this:

```
<textarea
    class="wm-textarea-notes"
    ng-model="noteEdit.note_value" 
    columns="1"  
    placeholder="Add a note"
    ng-readonly="isReadOnly()"></textarea>
```

So, somewhere in your controller you have to create that method that will return `true` or `false` for that `textarea` to determine its status.

Comment: Or what Victor Richa said (he beat me to it!). Though I would make a function in the controller rather than have the logic in the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

In latest angular (6/7), you can simply set it using **readonly**

```
<mat-form-field>
    <input matInput readonly="true" placeholder="{{placeholder}}" value="{{value}}">
</mat-form-field>
```